# Unity C# Code was working then when I saved It stopped working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had make a few peaces of code that I was on and It was all going fine in till I saved all of the script's and it came up with a whole lot of errors that I haven't seen or know how to fix, I'm new to all this coding stuff and my game was working fine then I saved and all hell broke out. I have the pics and code provided right here.

[image: First Line of errors.]

[image: Second Line of errors.]

```
public float speed;

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Vector2 moveVelocity;

void Start(){

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

void Update(){

    Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
}

void FixedUpdate(){

    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

}
```

**This is the first one...**

```
public Transform[] spawnPoints;
public GameObject[] monsters;
int randomSpawnPoint, randomMonster;
public static bool spawnAllowed;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    spawnAllowed = true;
    InvokeRepeating ("SpawnAMonster", 0f, 1f);
}

void SpawnAMonster()
{
    if (spawnAllowed) {
        randomSpawnPoint = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);
        randomMonster = Random.Range (0, monsters.Length);
        Instantiate (monsters [randomMonster], spawnPoints [randomSpawnPoint].position,
            Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've pasted doesn't show which classes it belongs to. Have you perhaps accidentally saved your scripts/class files in two duplicated files?

Comment: I will have to check that out, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error `The namespace <global namespace> already contains a definition for <class>` means you have two classes under no namespace that have the same name.

### What happened;

This usually happens when you move a script in your project and no not reload the solution in your code editor. When you save your script the code editor still thinks the file is in the old location, and saves it there. This is probably how you got two copies of the same script.

### To rectify;

Locate the two versions of the script, and use the inspector code preview to quickly decide which one you want to keep. Delete the other one, then close your code editor. Now you can choose where you want to move the script to. When you want to edit it, just open you code editor like normal.

### To avoid in the future;

When you move a script to a new location, make sure you close it in your code editor (i.e. close the tab). When you want to edit it, open it again. This will make sure that the code editor knows the correct path for the script, and doesn't make a save of it somewhere else